# How to integrate opencv2.2 with Qt4.7 in OSX 10.6.6?

Tags: opencv, osx-snow-leopard, qt4.6

I'm trying to integrate the opencv2.2 library with Qt4.7 creator on the mac and running into problems. Most of which I've resolved to some degree.
I downloaded the opencv2.2 tar.gz library and untar'ed it to a sub-directory under my home folder compiled it using CMake following [this guide](http://www.shiffman.net/2011/01/23/how-to-build-opencv-static-libraries-mac-os-x/) to use static libraries. (I unchecked the BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARIES and  USE_OMIT_FRAME_POINTER and checked the QT options)

My .pro file now currently looks like:

```
TARGET = openCVTst1
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /opt/local/include /usr/local/include

LIBS += -L/opt/local/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_features2d \
        -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml \
        -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_video -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

I have now simplified my test to just using:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
//MainWindow w;
//w.show();
cvNamedWindow( "My Window", 1 );
IplImage *img = cvCreateImage( cvSize( 640, 480 ), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
CvFont font;
double hScale = 1.0;
double vScale = 1.0;
int lineWidth = 1;
cvInitFont( &font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX | CV_FONT_ITALIC,
hScale, vScale, 0, lineWidth );
cvPutText( img, "Hello World!", cvPoint( 200, 400 ), &font,
cvScalar( 255, 255, 0 ) );
cvShowImage( "My Window", img );
cvWaitKey();
return a.exec();
}
```

in main.cpp and I still get the same errors. My compiler output:

```
Running build steps for project openCVTst1...
Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
Starting: "/usr/bin/make" -w
make: Entering directory `/Users/Inprimus/devProjects/openCVTst1-build-desktop'
/usr/bin/qmake -spec /usr/local/Qt4.7/mkspecs/macx-g++ -o Makefile ../openCVTst1/openCVTst1.pro
make: Leaving directory `/Users/Inprimus/devProjects/openCVTst1-build-desktop'
make: Entering directory `/Users/Inprimus/devProjects/openCVTst1-build-desktop'
g++ -headerpad_max_install_names -o openCVTst1.app/Contents/MacOS/openCVTst1 main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o   -F/Library/Frameworks -L/Library/Frameworks -L/opt/local/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_video -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -framework QtGui -L/tmp/qt-stuff-6474/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/lib -F/tmp/qt-stuff-6474/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/lib -framework QtCore 
ld: warning: directory '/tmp/qt-stuff-6474/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/lib' following -L not found
ld: warning: directory '/tmp/qt-stuff-6474/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0/lib' following -F not found
Undefined symbols:
  "QGLFormat::~QGLFormat()", referenced from:
      ViewPort::ViewPort(CvWindow*, int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::ViewPort(CvWindow*, int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
  "_glPushMatrix", referenced from:
      ViewPort::setGL(int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::setGL(int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
  "_gzclose", referenced from:
      _cvReleaseFileStorage in libopencv_core.a(persistence.o)
      _cvOpenFileStorage in libopencv_core.a(persistence.o)
      _cvOpenFileStorage in libopencv_core.a(persistence.o)
  "_glMatrixMode", referenced from:
      ViewPort::unsetGL()     in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::setGL(int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::setGL(int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)       in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
  "_glShadeModel", referenced from:
      ViewPort::initGL()     in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::ViewPort(CvWindow*, int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
  "_gzrewind", referenced from:
      icvRewind(CvFileStorage*)      in libopencv_core.a(persistence.o)
  "_glEnable", referenced from:
      ViewPort::initGL()     in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::initGL()     in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::initGL()     in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::ViewPort(CvWindow*, int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::ViewPort(CvWindow*, int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::ViewPort(CvWindow*, int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
  "QGLWidget::QGLWidget(QGLFormat const&, QWidget*, QGLWidget const*, QFlags<Qt::WindowType>)", referenced from:
      ViewPort::ViewPort(CvWindow*, int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
  "QGLFormat::QGLFormat(QFlags<QGL::FormatOption>, int)", referenced from:
      ViewPort::ViewPort(CvWindow*, int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
  "_glHint", referenced from:
      ViewPort::initGL()     in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::ViewPort(CvWindow*, int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
  "_gzgets", referenced from:
      icvGets(CvFileStorage*, char*, int)in libopencv_core.a(persistence.o)
  "_glPopMatrix", referenced from:
      ViewPort::unsetGL()     in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::unsetGL()     in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)       in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)       in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
  "_glFrustum", referenced from:
      ViewPort::icvgluPerspective(double, double, double, double)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::setGL(int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
  "_gzeof", referenced from:
      icvEof(CvFileStorage*)      in libopencv_core.a(persistence.o)
  "_glLoadIdentity", referenced from:
      ViewPort::setGL(int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
      ViewPort::setGL(int, int)in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
  "QGLWidget::grabFrameBuffer(bool)", referenced from:
      ViewPort::saveView()     in libopencv_highgui.a(window_QT.o)
  "_gzopen", referenced from:
      _cvOpenFileStorage in libopencv_core.a(persistence.o)
  "_gzputs", referenced from:
      icvPuts(CvFileStorage*, char const*)in libopencv_core.a(persistence.o)
make: Leaving directory `/Users/Inprimus/devProjects/openCVTst1-build-desktop'
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [openCVTst1.app/Contents/MacOS/openCVTst1] Error 1
The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code %2.
Error while building project openCVTst1 (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Sorry for the long edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to tell qt creator to link with the opencv libraries:

```
LIBS += -L/opt/local/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_video -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core
```

You only need to supply the libraries that you actually need. The order in which you supply the libraries is important (I am not sure if I got it right).

If `lib2` depends on `lib1`, you need to do `-llib2 -llib1`.

If you still get errors, consider posting the error messages that you can find in `Qt Creator` under the `compiler output` tab (CMD-4).

**Edit:**
Adding

```
QT += opengl
```

to your .pro file should fix that problem. See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtopengl.html for more information

Comment: Thanks I'll let you know how I get on

Comment: I have re-edited the original post to give a more detailed picture of my dev setup

Answer (score 1):

Did you follow [this guide](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/MacosxInstallGuide) - sorry not a mac user

Comment: Thanks.. I never saw that installation guide. I'll follow it and let you know